# Error while rendering json data [Reactjs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The data is in this form:

[image: this.props.tagsview]

```js
_getTags() {
    console.log(this.props.tagsview);
    return this.props.tagsview.map(tags => {
        var newItem = tags.map(p => <span className="tag" key={p.tag_id}>{p.name}</span>);
        return ({newItem);
    });
}
```

So when I'm running this I'm getting:

> error react.js:18893 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {newItem}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.(…)

What am I missing?
Is there another way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two issues here.. one is that you are returning a nested list
[[]] I think you probably wanted to return just a single list [].
you are also returning {newItem} from your outer map function.
That is not something React can render.
React needs a react element or a list of react elements.

did you mean to do:

```
return this.props.tagsview.map(tags => {
      return tags.map(p => <span className="tag" key={p.tag_id}>{p.name}</span>);
    });
```

or possibly

```
this.props.tagsview
  .reduce((tags, view) => [...tags, ...view.map(t =><span className="tag" key={p.tag_id}>{p.name}</span>)], [])
```